# Блок по всей ширине при увеличении масштаба

Tags: javascript, html, css

При увеличении масштаба background не адаптируется под текущие размеры и возникает такое пространство:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  font-size: 46px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/QROPyz

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо изменить стили у класса `menu` с таких:

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

на следующие:

```css
.menu {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Всё дело в том, что ваше описание устанавливает блочному (а `flex` - это блочный элемент) элементу с классом `main` ширину его родителя, а ширина родителя (`body` в данном случае установлена у вас в значение `100%`). Отсюда и проблема.

На текущий момент большинством браузеров поддерживаются новые значения для `width`: [max-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content), [min-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content) и [fit-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content), призванные разрешать подобные ситуации.
Вы можете поэкспериментировать с ними, но имейте в виду, хоть эти значения и поддерживаются браузерами, они всё ещё не входят в спецификации, так что не рекомендуется использовать их в боевых проектах.

Поэтому на сегодняшний день лучше остановиться на варианте с `inline-flex`.

Да, кстати, абсолютно незачем использовать `overflow: scroll` для `body` - полоса прокрутки итак будет появляться по мере необходимости.

Привожу итоговый пример целиком:

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background: #ccc;
}

.menu.max-content {
  display: flex;
  width: max-content;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background: #ccc;
}


.menu.fit-content {
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  font-size: 46px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
<p><center><em>display: inline-flex</em></center></p>
<hr>

<div class="menu max-content">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
<p><center><em>width: max-content</em></center></p>
<hr>

<div class="menu fit-content">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
<p><center><em>width: fit-content</em></center></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю тут проблема в том, что у вас запрещен переход элементов на новую строку и при сильном увеличении масштаба они не вмещаются в одну строку и вываливаются из блока, образуя белое пространство, т.к. по умолчанию у флекса стоит свойство `flex-wrap: nowrap`. В данном случае можно просто разрешить элементам `.item` переход на новую строку при отсутствии необходимого места, добавив классу `.menu` свойство `flex-wrap:wrap`.

Answer (score -1):

Убираем из `.menu` все флексы

```
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Говорим, что `.item` теперь `display: inline-block`

```
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 46px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Теперь элементы переходят на новую строку при узком экране

Если надо, чтобы блок растягивался `.item'ами`, то добавляем в `.menu` `white-space: nowrap`, чтобы элементы всегда были в строку и говорим, что он `inline-block`

```
.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Почему `display: flex` или `display: block` не тянутся контентом в ширину - не знаю, мжб кто подскажет в коментах.

Comment: хотелось бы с flex